# Inconsistent result from DataInputStream

Tags: java, datainputstream

I am having an issue using DataInputStream and DataOutputStream in Java that I have been unable to solve without some really silly measures and was wondering if anybody knew of a better way (I am VERY sure that there is one, but I haven't been able to find it).

Background: I want to be able to send a Json string to a server and have the server parse that string as an object. This needs to be language independent as a project I am working on for study requires that I have a heterogeneous system.

For the sake of the simplest possible example to show my problem I will exclude the creation of Gson/Json etc. as it can be recreated with any string. The code is as follows:

```
public class ServerSide {
    private final int PORT = 5001;
    private ServerSocket servSock;
    private Socket sock;
    private DataInputStream dis;
    private DataOutputStream dos;

    public ServerSide() throws IOException {
        servSock = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    }

    public void startListening() {
        try {
            sock = servSock.accept();
            dis = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            dis.read(bytes);

            String receivedMessage = new String(bytes);
            System.out.println("Message received: " + receivedMessage);
            sock.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

A simple test class that creates a ServerSide() and calls startListening in a while(true).

```
public class ClientSide {
    private final int PORT = 5001;
    private Socket socket;
    private DataOutputStream dos;

    public ClientSide() {

    }
    public void sendMessage(String m) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", PORT);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(m);
            System.out.println("Message sent: " + m);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

A simple test class that creates ClientSide() object and calls sendMessage("this is a test message");

The issue that I am having is that I only receive a partial message on the server side. I'm not sure if this is an issue with the Input or Output stream and have only been able to find work-arounds by writing and reading data multiple times and trimming the whitespace between. My first issue with this was when trying to send the Json string to a program I wrote in c#, where it would always send the first character ("{") and then the rest of the string in the next read. I countered this by sending a single space then ignoring this on the server side. The issue becomes worse on java-java when a seemingly random amount of the string is read in the first read.

A few example outputs of the above code for the server side is:

```
Message received: This is a tes

Message received: T

Message received: T

Message received: T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is.read(bytes);` [may return any number of bytes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])) - from one to `bytes.length`.

> Reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into the buffer array b. The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer. This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown.

Repeated calls to this method are required until it returns `-1` which means end-of-stream.

[Reading from and Writing to a Socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html) provides an example on how to read all data in line-oriented exchanges. For binary data (which DataStream is actually producing) you would need to use a combination of ByteArrayOutputStream, ByteArrayInputStream, and DataInputStream:

```
InputStream sis = sock.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while (int len = sis.read(bytes) > 0) {
    baos.write(bytes, 0, len);
}
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bais);
byte[] vBytes = new byte[baos.size()];
int sLen = dis.read(vBytes);
String receivedMessage = new String(vBytes, 0, sLen);
System.out.println("Message received: " + receivedMessage);
```

---

Note: the code above is answering specific question. Don't put it in production :)

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks very much. As a follow-up to this, how would you approach solving this issue?

Comment: @KevinAdams write the length first with `writeInt` and when reading use `readInt` and `readFully` to read the number of bytes which is exactly the length expected.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks the help provided by @Illya Kysil I have found a solution by changing my code to:

```
public class ClientSide {
    private final int PORT = 5001;
    private Socket socket;
    private DataOutputStream dos;

    public ClientSide() {

    }
    public void sendMessage(String m) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", PORT);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            byte[] mBytes = m.getBytes();
            dos.writeInt(mBytes.length);
            dos.write(mBytes);
            System.out.println("Message sent: " + m);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
public class ServerSide {
    private final int PORT = 5001;
    private ServerSocket servSock;
    private Socket sock;
    private DataInputStream dis;
    private DataOutputStream dos;

    public ServerSide() throws IOException {
        servSock = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    }

    public void startListening() {
        try {
            sock = servSock.accept();
            dis = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
            int length = dis.readInt();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
            dis.readFully(bytes);
            String receivedMessage = new String(bytes);
            System.out.println("Message received: " + receivedMessage.trim());
            dis.close();
            sock.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

This will first send an integer equal to the size of the byte Array of the message being sent. A buffer can be created of this length on the server side and the readFully method of DataInputStream can be used to fill this buffer.